# Use the Frobenius method to solve this differential equation

Tags: calculus

Solve, in a series, the differential equation:
$$(2+x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+(1+x)y=0$$
I can't understand how to apply the Frobenius method, please help.

Comment: As you said..I searched the website, but i can't get it, please give me any link

Comment: @MikeWilliams Dont ever ask math questions on a math Q&A forum. How dare anyone ask math questions on this site.  How dare any patron come onto this site to even answer questions! My god, what has this place become?!?!